# Why is var var = "" allowed but not string string = ""

Tags: c#, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Why can I create a class named “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548988/c-why-can-i-create-a-class-named-var)

Why is `var var = ""` allowed as valid c# code but `string string = ""` isn't? They are both keywords are they not?

Comment: It's a "contextual keyword", see the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548988/c-why-can-i-create-a-class-named-var

Comment: It seems like the C# guys have been doing that a lot more starting with 3.0.

Comment: `string` is a valid name. You just have to write it as `@string`

Comment: Thanks greg, it doesn't mention contextual keywords in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx.